# For loop and Conditionals in pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have this DataFrame and I need to write a conditionals to extract only the starred Energy.

```
Energy  Time
0       80
0       82 
0       84
0       86
287**   88
287     90
287     91
287     92
0       94
0       96
0       98
302**   100
302     102
302     104
302     106
0       108
0       110
```

The idea is to accepts Energy values when Energy(t)>0 & Energy(t-1)==0.

I tried creating a for loop

```
set_time=set(df.loc[:,'Time'])
list_time=list(set_time)
for t, time in enumerate(list_time):
     if df['Energy'][t] > 0 & df['Energy'][t-1]==0:
        print(df['Energy'],t)
```

But I get errors. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: KeyError: 'Energy'

Answer (score 1):

There is one way

```
v=df.eq(0).Energy.cumsum()

df.groupby(df.eq(0).Energy.cumsum()).head(2).loc[df.groupby(v).Energy.filter(lambda x : x.ne(0).any()).index].dropna()

Out[1538]: 
    Energy   Time
3      0.0   86.0
4    287.0   88.0
10     0.0   98.0
11   302.0  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, pls could you explain a little bit what did you do? what is eq(0) cumsum()...?

Comment: @Annalix cumsum :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html,

eq == '='